# Keep aspect ratio of background on GridView

Tags: java, android, gridview

I have a image as background on my GridView and I want it to keep its aspect ratio.
I want it to match the height of the phone and use the width that matches the aspect ratio.

Here is the current code:

```
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:id="@+id/gridview"
android:scaleType="centerInside"
android:background="@drawable/gytbg"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:columnWidth="10dp"
android:numColumns="2"
android:verticalSpacing="20dp"
android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
android:gravity="center"
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
```

This should fit the image to the height of the GridView, maintaining the aspect ratio, and crop the remaining width (unless the image's width is smaller than that of the GridView when the height is matched).

E.g.

If you have a GridView that is 400dp in width and 800dp in height

An image of 600 x 600 will fit the height and then crop the remaining width.

If however the GridView was landscape (400dp in width and 300dp in height) then a 600 x 600 image would fit the width and then crop the height.

If you only ever want it to fit the height (assuming that the height might change programmatically or due to different device's screens), I would suggest making the image considerably wider so that even when presented with a GridView with a very wide aspect ratio, it will choose to fit the height, and crop the width.